# How to do calculation with loop number but without counting in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am now working on a python algorithm. I have a for loop to generate some numbers. These numbers will be used as indices to generate strings.

I have these codes:

```
val=4
ind=[]
for i in range(1,7):
        for j in range(val,val+i):
            val = val+1
            ind.append(j)
            if(i < 6):
                boundNode.insert(j, 'x%d' % (j-(2*i+1)))
            constraint_sty1 = str(boundNode[j]) + " + " + str(boundNode[j+1]) 
         val = j + 3
```

**The problem here is: The `boundNode[j]` works to get what I demand, However, `boundNode[j+1]` encounters error**, It seems that `j+1` has been viewed as a sign to do some other operations here. I tried to only `print(j+1)`, it can also print the indices I want. I'd like to know if there's any solution  to this.

This is the output of `print(boundNode[j])` and `print(boundNode[j+1])`

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10 x11 x12 x13 x14 x15 20 23 25 26 27 28
```

```
12 16 16 19 19 19 22 22 22 22 25 25 25 25 25 23 25 26 27 28 28
```

To define the larger picture, `boundNode` is a list like this:

```
boundNode = [0, 4, 6, 7, 12, 9, 16, 11, 19, 13, 22, 14, 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
```

I use 2 for loops to generate indices like `4, 7, 8 , 11, 12 , 13 ...` and put `x1`  to `x15` into `boundNode`. And the boundNode is now like:

```
[0, 4, 6, 7, 'x1', 12, 9, 'x2', 'x3', 16, 11, 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 19, 13, 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 22, 14, 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
```

What I am going to next is to use the indices to point to bound nodes and generate strings. Everything is going well except `boundNode[j+1]`

Comment: May be `boundNode[j+1]` gets overflow item

Comment: @toRex I'm not sure if it is overflow. I've edited the post. It shows the result of `print(boundNode[j])` is more than `print(boundNode[j+1])`. Will this be useful to explain what happened?

Comment: Is 28 the last element of `boundNode` list?  If so then after showing the last element of  j, it shouldn't find `j+1` index

Comment: @toRex Yes, 28 is the last element. But the problem is that the ideal result here is unique numbers while now it shows 1*12, 2*16, 3*19...This is not what i demand.

Comment: larger picture, what are you trying to do?  What is `boundNode`? What is `val`? What is `ind`? Neither is defined in your question.

Comment: @PierreD I have edited the original post to provide more details about the large picture. I'd appreciate it if you can have look at them.

Answer (score 1):

When the number of elements in `boundNode` is less than 7+val, you will get that error

> IndexError: list index out of range

This error happens because you specify a range beyond the list.
The corrected code would be:

```
val=5
ind=[]
boundNode = [0, 4, 6, 7, 12, 9, 16, 11, 19, 13, 22, 14, 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
# boundNode = [0, 4, 6, 7, 'x1', 12, 9, 'x2', 'x3', 16, 11, 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 19, 13, 'x7', 'x8', 'x9', 'x10', 22, 14, 'x11', 'x12', 'x13', 'x14', 'x15', 25, 15, 20, 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 28]
boundNode = list(range(1,13))
for i in range(1,7):
    for j in range(val,val+i):
        val = val+1
        ind.append(j)
        if(i < 6):
            boundNode.insert(j, 'x%d' % (j-(2*i+1)))

        constraint_sty1 = str(boundNode[j]) + " + " + str(boundNode[j+1])
        print(constraint_sty1)
```

you will get results of the following:

```
x2 + 6
x1 + 6
x2 + 6
x1 + 6
x2 + 6
x3 + 6
x2 + 6
x3 + 6
x4 + 6
x5 + 6
x4 + 6
x5 + 6
x6 + 6
x7 + 6
x8 + 6
6 + 7
7 + 8
8 + 9
9 + 10
10 + 11
11 + 12
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kardi. But the problem here is not about the for loop. It's that I can successfully receive what i want in `str(boundNode[j])` but not in the `j+1` one. I guess the question should be how to avoid `j+1` starting a new loop when pointing to a list.

Comment: Your question is actually unclear. First you said about the error, which has been answered here. Now you change the question about double for-loop. Why do you need to combine strings and integers in  one array anyway? Separate them into two arrays would be simpler. You should probably explain what are you trying to accomplish in big picture. What should be the correct end result. Even if you did not achieve it in your code yet, at least you need to know your goal, which is not stated in your question.